# I'm unable to redirect to a new view from a Link sended to an email

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am wanting to do a password recovery using email, in the view I enter the email, valid that it exists, and an email is sent to you with a link that when you click on it, redirects you to the view to change the password. This all works fine, but the link I send "doesn´t exist".

> Cannot find this page (localhost)No web page found for address https://localhost:1111/ChangePasswords/ChangePassword/

My controller: `public class ChangePasswords: Controller`

View:

```
public ActionResult ChangePassword()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

Email:

```
 string urlDomain = "https://localhost:1111/";
 string url = urlDomain + "/ChangePasswords/ChangePassword/;
 builder.HtmlBody = "<p>RECOVER PASSWORD</p><br>" +
                    "<a href='" + url + "'>Click to recover</a>";
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is because you are making a request to the localhost address and not the ip address where your application is running. When the address is localhost the computer makes the request to itself. It works during development because the browser and the application are running on the same computer. But if you try to access the application from different computer it won't work.

Comment: I've test in my side with a class like `public class Test : Controller` and the file is put out of the `Controller` folder but still everything worked well. So I'm afraid you need to provide more code if what @DimitrisMaragkos said didn't help you.

Comment: I think that `urlDomain` don't work, I tried using the complete path ("https://localhost:1111//ChangePasswords/ChangePassword/") and worked